# Which inactive users have the most reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, statistics

I'm referring to users like [Arturo Magidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/742/arturo-magidin). Let me know if there's a better adjective than 'inactive', but Arturo Magidin's profile encapsulates it:

> With the move of MathOverflow into the SE network, this account is now associated with dormant accounts in math.SE and other sites in the network. While I plan to continue my (generally low-level) participation in MO, my current plans do not include restarting my participation in those other sites. Therefore, I will be ignoring any comments or pings that reach me from those sites, unless and until I resume my active participation there.
>
> I remain "gone for the foreseeable future" from math.SE, tex.SE, and meta.SE. Though I may very occasionally post a comment or an answer, these do not signify a desire to re-start my heavy prior participation.

Of course "inactive" encompasses users that abandoned their accounts, whether announced in their profile or not.

Comment: How do you define inactive? What specifically are you trying to achieve? Did you gave [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) a try?

Comment: Bad example, that user is still active on that site.

Answer (score 3):

If you define 'active' as 'their Last seen date on their [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) is long ago', it's relatively simple to figure this out with a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1069630/inactive-users-with-the-most-reputation):

[image]

(Keep in mind SEDE is refreshed once a week, on Sunday morning, so if they visited this week, they'd still appear in the results.)

Comment: `SEDE is refreshed once a week, on Sunday morning`. Is it safe to assume it's WRT to UTC TIME as used by SE sites? What time in the morning approximately? Can you please update it in the answer?

Comment: @NimeshNeema it's in the [SEDE FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq). I hope you don't mind me not updating the answer, because then I'd have to update [48 other answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A295232+%22Sunday+morning%22) as well ...

Comment: FAQs should do. However, the link in the comment is broken (it refers to the current user): `https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+%22Sunday+morning%22`

Comment: Oops, thanks for spotting that in time so I could edit my comment :)